# ZF2 How to set search form in layout

Tags: forms, layout, zend-framework2

What is the right way to set a (search) form with Zend Framework 2 in the layout.ptml who is visible on any page of the website?

Thanks in advance.

Nick

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is really simple to set any variables to all layouts in ZF2 by EventManager, just attach the EVENT_RENDER event such as:

```
class Module
{
    public function onBootstrap($e)
    {
        $app = $e->getParam('application');
        $app->getEventManager()->attach(MvcEvent::EVENT_RENDER, array($this, 'setFormToView'), 100);
    }

    public function setFormToView($event)
    {
        $form = new MyForm();
        $viewModel = $event->getViewModel();
        $viewModel->setVariables(array(
            'form' => $form,
        ));
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, it's simple!.. :) Thanks a lot!

Comment: If the 'form' is placed not in a layout.phtml, but in some partial, then it can be accessed as `$form = $this->layout()->form;`

Comment: Is it possible to extend that form in controller? I mean in some controller I want to add to form some inputs, in other controller add some select etc...

Answer (score 0):

For view in layout use:

```
    <?php if ($user = $this->identity()): ?>
        <?php echo 'Login with user' . $this->escapeHtml($user->nome); ?>
        | <a href="<?php echo $this->url('auth/default', array('controller' => 'index', 'action' => 'logout'));?>"><?php echo $this->translate('Sair'); ?></a>
    <?php else: ?>
    <?php
        echo $this->form()->openTag($form);
        echo "<h5>Forneça seu login e senha </h5>";
        echo $this->formRow($form->get('username'));
        echo $this->formRow($form->get('password'));
        echo $this->formRow($form->get('rememberme'));
        echo $this->formSubmit($form->get('submit'));
        echo $this->form()->closeTag();
    ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```